# woocommerce_order_refunded action hook not working

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to add an action that is associated to the woocommerce_order_refunded hook, which is to add the refund id to order note whenever a (partialy/fully) refund is created. (You may find an example from whenever a refund is made, there's a note that the stock increases)

[image: order]

But the hook doesn't seem working, here is my code:

```
function add_order_refund_note ($order_id, $refund_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order_refunds = $order->get_refunds();

        foreach ( $order_refunds as $refund ) {
            $order->add_order_note( "Refund ID:" . $refund_id );

        }

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_refunded', 'add_order_refund_note', 10, 2 );
```

I don't know if there was any problem with the `woocommerce_order_refunded`. I also tried the two other action hooks

```
woocommerce_order_partially_refunded
woocommerce_order_fully_refunded
```

but nothing works also.

Can anyone give me a solution for it? Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had much experience with this function, but foreach is usually used when you want to repeat something that may be in an object and treat it differently (`$order_refunds`), thus try changing your `foreach()` command so `$order_refunds` becomes `$refund`.

Inside the current `foreach()` your calling on: `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`.

Try:

```
    foreach ( $order_refunds as $refund ) {
        $refund->add_order_note( "Refund ID:" . $refund_id );
    }
```